# Why don't I get product price in responce from eBay?

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, web-services

I get ebay product information this way:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?
   callname=FindProducts&
   responseencoding=XML&
   appid=YourAppIDHere&
   siteid=0&
   version=525&
   QueryKeywords=harry%20potter&
   AvailableItemsOnly=true&
   MaxEntries=2
```

But I don't get product price in responce. Should I shange the request parameters? Or may be I should use another method of ebay Web services to get this information?

The response is

```
<FindProductsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2012-11-30T06:54:54.713Z</Timestamp>
<Ack>Success</Ack>
<Build>E799_CORE_BUNDLED_15523174_R1</Build>
<Version>799</Version>
<ApproximatePages>700</ApproximatePages>
<MoreResults>true</MoreResults>
<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
<Product>
<DomainName>DVDs</DomainName>
<DetailsURL>
http://syicatalogs.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?PageSyiProductDetails&IncludeAttributes=1&ShowAttributesTable=1&ProductMementoString=119128:2:1049:4276619924:441341764:7a3b4632d7a0c4ee860c374349c61b36:1:1:1:5000000672733
</DetailsURL>
<DisplayStockPhotos>true</DisplayStockPhotos>
<ProductID type="Reference">110258144</ProductID>
<ProductID type="UPC">883929182879</ProductID>
<ItemSpecifics>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Movie Rating</Name>
<Value>PG-13 (MPAA)</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Genre</Name>
<Value>Childrens</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Format</Name>
<Value>DVD</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Work Name</Name>
<Value>Harry Potter: Complete 8-Film Collection</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Region Code</Name>
<Value>Region 1</Value>
</NameValueList>
</ItemSpecifics>
<ReviewCount>195</ReviewCount>
<StockPhotoURL>
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/$(KGrHqV,!g0E6ZCwQ)wpBOuWbUNB,g~~_6.JPG?set_id=89040003C1
</StockPhotoURL>
<Title>
Harry Potter: Complete 8-Film Collection (DVD, 2011, 8-Disc Set)
</Title>
</Product>
<Product>
<DomainName>DVDs</DomainName>
<DetailsURL>
http://syicatalogs.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?PageSyiProductDetails&IncludeAttributes=1&ShowAttributesTable=1&ProductMementoString=119128:2:1049:1597262630:429151180:bf834db05cfb5150fe073087ebe92117:1:1:1:1415162318
</DetailsURL>
<DisplayStockPhotos>true</DisplayStockPhotos>
<ProductID type="Reference">99846530</ProductID>
<ProductID type="UPC">883929139446</ProductID>
<ItemSpecifics>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Movie Rating</Name>
<Value>PG-13 (MPAA)</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Genre</Name>
<Value>Science-Fiction/Fantasy</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Director</Name>
<Value>David Yates</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Format</Name>
<Value>DVD</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Work Name</Name>
<Value>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part I</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Region Code</Name>
<Value>Region 1</Value>
</NameValueList>
<NameValueList>
<Name>Producer</Name>
<Value>David Heyman</Value>
</NameValueList>
</ItemSpecifics>
<ReviewCount>163</ReviewCount>
<StockPhotoURL>
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/$(KGrHqF,!l0E2DwP)(v!BNo16imfYQ~~_6.JPG?set_id=89040003C1
</StockPhotoURL>
<Title>
Harry Potter and the Death
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this Link](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#sampledescriptionitemspecifics) : [Getting Item Descriptions and Item Specifics](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#sampledescriptionitemspecifics)
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html#sampledescriptionitemspecifics

URL format (HTTP GET). See also the non-wrapped version of this URL. For results in a format other than XML, 
specify a different value for responseencoding.

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?
   callname=GetSingleItem&
   responseencoding=XML&
   appid=YourAppIDHere&
   siteid=0&
   version=515&
   ItemID=180126682091&
   IncludeSelector=Description,ItemSpecifics
```

You have to pass ItemID to get [Detailed Description](http://www.developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/index.html).

Comment: is itemID is the same as <ProductID type="Reference">110258144</ProductID> or <ProductID type="UPC">883929182879</ProductID>?

Comment: check this link : http://www.developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Going by [this info](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html#Response.ItemArray.Item.BuyItNowPrice) it seems like certain values have a conditional occurrence in the response. So maybe you may need to check if price is firstly returned or not by the response and if not, query another api with say the product id value. HTH.